# Error when trying to create an empty text file using Ansible Playbooks

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a simple playbook I am trying to run that should create an empty file on a Windows target:

```
---

- hosts: 10.25.42.55
  tasks:
  - name: Creating a file
    win_file:
      path: C:\Temp\subfolder\test.txt
      state: touch
    become: yes
```

I try to execute the playbook on the command line by doing `ansible-playbook pb.yaml` and get an error that says the following:

`ERROR! an error occurred while trying to read the file '/home/ansadmd/ansible/host_vars/10.25.42.55/vault.yml': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ansadmd/ansible/host_vars/10.25.42.55/vault.yml'`

I am not sure what the vault.yml file has to do with running pb.yaml to create an empty text file or how to get around this error.

I tried an ad-hoc command of `ansible 10.25.42.55 -m win_file -a 'path=C:\Temp\subfolder\test.txt state=touch'` and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

All host variables are read automatically when you execute either a playbook or an ad-hoc command. Your host variable file does not have necessary read permissions for your user.

Try something like: `chmod u+r /home/ansadmd/ansible/host_vars/10.25.42.55/*`

If this doesn't work, you may need to elevate your privileges to fix the permissions.